# EmberJS Processing before returning model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise, ember-cli

How can one do processing on an ember model before returning it in the hook? I currently have something along the following lines in a route

```
model: function (params) {
        var list_of_modelAs = [];

        this.store.find('modelA').then(function (modelAs) {
            modelAs.forEach ( function (modelA) {
                modelA.get('modelB').then(function(modelB) {
                    if (modelB.get('id') == params.modelB_id) {
                        list_of_modelAs.push(modelA)
                    }
                })
            })
        });

        return list_of_modelAs;
    }
```

Where modelA and modelB of course are models defined with Ember-Data.

I'm essentially creating an array of models but filtering them first. Really what I want to do is just filter the array of models, but I couldn't figure out another way to do it as `modelB` is a foreign model (`modelA` belongsTo `modelB`, i.e. each modelA has a modelB). Ideally what I'm trying to do is something like:

`return this.store.find('modelA', where modelA.modelB.id = someValue)`

The problem is, of course, that because of promises and such, only an empty `list_of_modelAs` is returned and the model comes up empty.

I assume I have to somehow structure this to return a promise from the model hook, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: one question before I post an answer .. `modelA.get` returns a promise, but `modelB.get` does not, is that correct? Or does it depend on the argument passed in to get?

Comment: I'm not sure. Wouldn't both of them return a promise?

Comment: Not according to your code

Comment: According to my code? Isn't whether they return a promise or not dependent on Ember? modelA and modelB are both Ember-Data models, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: yes, but your code uses `modelA.get` as if it returns a promise, and the next line uses `modelB.get` as if it returns an actual value. That's what I mean by _according to your code_ Not having access to the rest of your code base, I can only draw assumptions based on the code you've posted

Comment: `modelB.get('id')` is getting the actual id field from modelB. My understanding if you are getting actual fields (`DS.attr`s) that they aren't promises, but that relations (`DS.belongsTo`s) are.

Comment: cool, I'm not up on ember, but I do have a possible solution

Comment: What do you want the model hook to return? In other words, what do you want the model used in the controller/template to be?

Comment: the filtered list of model As

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return a promise from the model hook

As I have next to no knowledge of ember, I can only presume that the above is what you are attempting to achieve - this will achieve that

```
model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('modelA') // important you do a return here, to return the promise
    .then(function (modelAs) { // modelAs is an array of modelA - we can use map to change this to an array of modelA.get('modelB') promises
        return Promise.all(modelAs.map(function (modelA) { // Promise.all resolves when the array of promises resolves, it resolves to an array of results
            return modelA.get('modelB').then(function (modelB) { // just do the asynch stuff here, return modelA if the id is OK, otherwise return null which will be filtered out later
                if (modelB.get('id') == params.modelB_id) {
                    return modelA;
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }));
    })
    .then(
        function(data) { // data is an array of values returned from Promise.all - filter out the null values as they are the ones that don't have the correct ModelB id
            return data.filter(function(datum) {
                return datum !== null;
            });
        }
    );
    // the final return value will be a promise of an array of ModelA whose ModelB has the required `id`
}
```

called using

```
???.model(params)
.then(function(modelAs) {
    // NOTE: modelAs is an array of modelA's not promises
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Just to make sure I understand what you did: So you did the original store.find, which returns a promise, then you called `then` on it, which specifies a function to execute when the promise is fullfilled, twice, then in that function? then things get a little murky for me.

Comment: let me add some comments :D

Comment: let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: that's extremely helpful, thanks. How do returns from `.then` clauses work exactly?